# How to get a count each unique element in the general array

Tags: php, arrays, count

Good day.

Code:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
          [0]=> array(3) { 
               [0]=> string(11) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(2950) 
          }
          [1]=> array(3) { 
               [0]=> string(8) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(2955)  
          } 
          [2]=> array(3) { 
               [0]=> string(8) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(1335)  
          }
          [3]=> array(3) { 
               [0]=> string(8) "art_7883" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(4335)  
          }
}
```

**I get array unique elements:**

```
$arr_uniq = array();
foreach ($all_array as $keys => $elms ) {
    if(!in_array($elms[0], $arr_uniq)) {
        $arr_uniq[] = $elms[0];
    }
}
```

***Tell me pleasse how to get a count each unique element in the general array?***

result should been next:

**art_7880** - 3

**art_7883** - 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$all_array` is subarray of your main array in your `var_dump` snipett, the general idea is

```
$result = array();
foreach ($all_array as $elms)    
    $result[$elms[0]]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_count_values()`

http://php.net/array_count_values

You should be able to easily apply this function.

Comment: Jessica, please explain. i get array with all unique elements. what step i should make next?